# Windows Service in C# that Imports from Excel and Dumps data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net

I need a Windows Service Application, which has timer in it, which checks a folder after 12 hours, and opens all the excel files which are Marked UNUSED, and dumps the data into a table in SQL Server 2005 and then edits the name of the excel file to USED. Continues to do it on daily basis.

Comment: Good story, I once had to write a service, it was a good day. :)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Steve: Sorry, I forgot to highlight the question efficiently.. I am newbie.. :) Actually, I dont know how to make this entire thing.. Its a part of my project. Any links or solution if available, kindly help me out with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Murtaza.  Generally you'll get the best feedback on here if you can narrow down your question to be about a specific problem (rather than a whole project), and ideally with (a small portion of) the code you've tried so far.  See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is all possible with SQL Server and SSIS :

- SSIS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx
- SQL Server Maintenance Plans : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx
- Importing Excel: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1393/import-excel-unicode-data-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Let us know if you have any trouble setting it up.

Comment: Thanks for the links. But I was looking forward for specifically Windows Service, that may work automatically time to time without any kind of management/instructions needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have to stick to a service with timer these links/informations might be of interest for you:

- Creating a Basic Windows Service in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

To use a timer, simply create a `System.Timers.Timer` as field of your class and initialize it in the OnStart Event of the Service like this:

```
// configuring polling timer
this.downlaodTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
this.downlaodTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimerElapse);

// set timer intervall to 1 hour
this.downlaodTimer.Interval = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

// start timer
this.downlaodTimer.Start();
```

Also, you should pause it in service events like OnStop, OnPause and start it again in OnContinue.

For the "import from Excel" part christofr's links should be helpful.

Hope this helps - good luck ;)